# How to reset columns order in jquery plugin datatables?

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

such as I have some array data like this:

```
{"aaData": [
[
  "Trident",
  "Internet Explorer 4.0",
  "Win 95+",
  "4",
  "X"
]
```

]}

but I don't want it show as this order: "Trident", "Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X".
if I wan "Win 95+" at the first column and I don't want to change the source data order. waht can I config in aoColumns option?

Answer (score 0):

You cas use "mData" property like this:

```
"aoColumns": [
              {"mData": 2 },
              {"mData": 0 },
              {"mData": 1 },
              {"mData": 3 },
              {"mData": 4 },
            ]
```

Integer of "mData" treated as an array index for the data source.

Here http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns you can read more about it.